# Jquery accordion open on click of another accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have four accordions as in the following code , when i close the accordion BackupCoWorker4 automatically accordion BackupCoWorker2 should open making everything else closed. please see this fiddle below .thanks in advance.

```js
$("#BackupCoAcc1").accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  active: false,
  heightStyle: "content"
});
$("#BackupCoAcc2").accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  active: false,
  heightStyle: "content"
});
$("#BackupCoAcc3").accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  active: false,
  heightStyle: "content"
});
$("#BackupCoAcc4").accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  active: false,
  heightStyle: "content"
});
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <div id="BackupCoAcc1" class="accordion">
    <h3>Backup CoWorker1(s)</h3>
    <div id="BackupDiv1"> Jobs for:<span id="bckupWorkers1">&nbsp;Me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="BackupCoAcc2" class="accordion">
    <h3>Backup CoWorker2(s)</h3>
    <div id="BackupDiv2"> Jobs for:<span id="bckupWorkers2">&nbsp;Me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="BackupCoAcc4" class="accordion">
    <h3>Backup CoWorker4(s)</h3>
    <div id="BackupDiv4"> Jobs for:<span id="bckupWorkers4">&nbsp;Me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="BackupCoAcc3" class="accordion">
    <h3>Backup CoWorker3(s)</h3>
    <div id="BackupDiv3"> Jobs for:<span id="bckupWorkers3">&nbsp;Me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And where is the fiddle?

Comment: @LShetty  the code i have posted along with the question above ...run the snippet :)

Comment: @Glorfindel..dude i have directly attached the snippet along with question..please follow that

Comment: @charanbabu you know we can't edit your code in the snippet above and help you debug. Don't you?

Comment: sorry guys....I am new to stackoverflow....@LShetty...dats y a small mistake....

Answer (score 0):

> its worked for me

$("#BackupCoAcc4").on("click",function(e){
         $("#BackupCoAcc1").accordion({
             active:0
         });
     });